# Series object has no attribute 'astype' when comparing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a new column to my dataframe where I am comparing it to another dataframe. It's supposed to output a '1' or '0' in the new column as to whether the value in the comparison workbook exists in either column 0 or 1 of my existing workbook.

I am encountering Series object has no attribute 'astype' error when running my script.

```
df_comparing = pd.read_excel(fName, sheet_name=0, index_col=None) #compare this to my the next dataframe

df_compare_basis = pd.read_excel(readxl, index_col=None) #is the basis for comparison

df_comparing['Match'] = (
    df_comparing.iloc[0].isin(df_compare_basis['DataLineID'])
) | (df_comparing.iloc[1].isin(df_compare_basis['DataLineID'])).astpye(int)
```

I tried another method using numpy array with:

```
df_comparing['Match'] = np.where((
    df_comparing.iloc[0].isin(df_compare_basis['DataLineID'])
) | (df_comparing.iloc[1].isin(df_compare_basis['DataLineID'])), 1, 0)
```

but as the datasets are different lengths, I am encountering ValueError: Length of values does not match the length of the index.

What's the best way to address the above?

Comment: `iloc[0]` gives first row as series. To select first column, do `iloc[:,0]`. Are you sure its `Series object has no attribute 'astype' ` error @cd-6?

Comment: yep, even adjusting to iloc[:,0] just now still has same error, I've updated question to show me grabbing the dataframes

Comment: Is type of `df_compare_basis` a dict or DataFrame?

Comment: It’s a data frame, I’m comparing a single column in df_compare_basis to 2 columns in df_comparing